# Sparkling Water (pysparkling) in Spark Standalone cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, h2o

I've set up a Spark Standalone cluster (1 master and 2 slaves, to start with) and like to use Pysparkling on in. My understanding is that I have to install h2o_pysparkling_2.0 (I'm running Spark 2.0.2), requests, tabulate, colorama and future on the master instance (I'm using Anaconda distribution, so that I shouldn't care about numpy and the like):

```
pip install h2o_pysparkling_2.0
pip install requests 
pip install tabulate
pip install future
pip install colorama
```

However, I don't know whether I must install the same packages on the slave instances. I think so, but I'd like to know whether any of you have some information on this. Available [official documentation](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/rel-2.0/py/README.rst) and [blog posts](https://weidongzhou.wordpress.com/2017/11/06/h2o-vs-sparkling-water/) do not provide specific information on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python dependencies need to be available on all nodes where Spark/Sparkling Water is running - that means on both executors and driver.

This is because the operations are executed in parallel and require the same dependencies as on driver. What I would suggest is to run your Spark application in the uniform environment - ie, have same environment, dependencies for all spark executors and driver to prevent bunch of issues

Comment: It's what I though but wanted to be sure. On the other hand, you possibly missed the last sentence. I'd be happy to know it :-)

Comment: Thanks to you, I've actually deployed the same environment in driver and executors and works fine :-) Thanks again